# How to load configuration parameters from XML files into Spring MVC Controllers?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've noticed that I can load a config parameter into a bean using something like this in `application-context.xml`:

```
<beans:bean id="foo" class="com.foo.FooBean">
    <beans:property name="foo" value="${foo}" />
</beans:bean>
```

What about if I want to access the `foo` value in a Controller without instantiating a bean? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to get the value in your controller without instantiating FooBean?

Comment: Why not use Danny's suggestion and inject ${foo} into your controller from a properties file?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `@Value` annotation with `util:properties`

```
<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:com/foo/bar/props.properties"/>
```

And in your controller class, assuming you have a property with key 'foo':

```
@Value("#{props.foo}")
public void setFoo(String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Please refer to this link to read more about it

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer